# using addChildViewController the UITableViewDatasource methods are no being called

Tags: ios, uitableview

using addChildViewController the UITableViewDatasource methods are no being called
none of datasource or delegates methods
Is there a way to solve this?

Bellow I have added the code of the parent controller that is calling the addChildViewController method.
And bellow that, I posted the child viewController code (whithout the UIViewTableDatasource)

Parent Code:

```
 self.commentsController = [[CommentsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"CommentsVC" bundle:nil restaurant:_resto];

    UIView *newview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.viewComments.bounds];


    self.commentsController.view = newview;
    self.commentsController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.viewComments addSubview:self.commentsController.view];

    [self addChildViewController:self.commentsController];
```

Child Code

```
- (id)initWithRestaurant:(Restaurant *)resto{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    _resto = resto;
    if(resto.reviews.count == 0){
        dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("q_getReviews", NULL);
        dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
            id resultReviews = [[RestaurantManager sharedInstance] getRestaurantReviews:resto orderBy:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if([resultReviews isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]){
                    NSError *err = (NSError *)resultReviews;
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:err.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    [alert show];
                }else{
                    self.resto.reviews =  (NSMutableArray *)resultReviews;
                    [((UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:kTblComments]) reloadData];
                }
            });
        });
        dispatch_release(myQueue);
    }
}
return self;
```

}

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
UITableView *tblComments = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tblComments.tag = kTblComments;
tblComments.delegate = self;
tblComments.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:tblComments];
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

I was assigning a new view that doesn't contains the uiTable.

```
UIView *newview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.viewComments.bounds];
self.commentsController.view = newview;
```

Just removing that, the code works!

Answer (score 0):

1. In the parent code you are calling `[[CommentsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"CommentsVC" bundle:nil restaurant:_resto];` for initializing the child view controller, but in your child view controller you are loading the data that I suppose you are using for the table view so it's possible that your data source to be empty.
2. It's to early to call `[((UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:kTblComments]) reloadData];` in the init method, the table view is not `initialized` yet.

So make sure that you are calling the right init methods for your child view controller and also make sure that your table view data source is not empty and after that you can call `[yourTableView reloadData]` after you init the table view, set it's delegate and add as subview.

Comment: That's not solves the problem. Because it works when i change the the addChildViewController by uiNavigationController push